# Looping through an array of objects to create radio button options using react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component in which I want to include some radio buttons.

Single.js

```
class Single extends Component {
render() {

        const {questions, choices, actions} = this.props;
        const {id} = this.props.params;
        const i = questions.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
        const question_obj = questions[i];
        return ( 
                <div className = 'QuestionSection'>
                <h2> Poll Your Choice </h2> 
                {question_obj.question_text} 
                <form ref = 'choiceForm'> 
                {
                    choices.map((choice, i) => <Choice {...this.props} key = {i} i = {i} choice = {choice}/>)
                }
                </form> </div>
               );
        }
}
```

Array of choices objects are mapped to a different component Choices.js where each choice is rendered as a radio button.

Since each object is rendered separately, I am not able to handle radio button selection.

How can I loop through this array of choices objects to create radio button with each object and handle selection/submit of radio button options?

Comment: check redux-form it will make your life easier http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/examples/simple/

Comment: Problem is how can I get all choices in Single component only?